# Get future multi-day event entries with custom date field

Tags: templating, datetime, forloop, custom-field

I have an event section with custom fields for eventDate and eventEndDate.

I'm listing upcoming events in my template using:

```
{% for event in craft.entries.section('events').eventDate('>='~now).limit(3).order('eventDate ASC') %}
```

This works fine for single day events. But multi-day events disappear after the first day, when I want them to be listed until the event is over. I can't do .eventEndDate('>='~now) because the Event End Date field is left blank for single day events. Is there a way to add an OR to my query to get events with future eventDates OR events with future eventEndDates?

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest solution would be to make the `eventEndDate` field required even for single day events. Then you could do something like this:

```
{% for event in craft.entries({
  section:'events', 
  eventEndDate:'>= '~now,
  limit: 3, 
  order:'startDate'
}) %}
```

Given you have 3 events:

1. Starts Monday, ends Friday.
2. Starts Wednesday, ends Thursday.
3. Starts Thursday, ends Thursday.

On Wednesday, you'll still see those events in order (1,2,3).